# Notifying Google PubSub when Dataflow job is complete

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a way to publish a message onto Google Pubsub after a Google Dataflow job completes? We have a need to notify dependent systems that the processing of incoming data is complete. How could Dataflow publish after writing data to the sink?

**EDIT:** 
We want to notify after a pipeline completes writing to GCS. Our pipeline looks like this:

```
 
Pipeline.create(options)
                .apply(....)
                .apply(AvroIO.Write.named("Write to GCS")
                             .withSchema(Extract.class)
                             .to(options.getOutputPath())
                             .withSuffix(".avro"));
p.run();
```

If we add logic outside of the pipeline.apply(...) methods we are notified when the code completes execution, not when the pipeline is completed. Ideally we could add another `.apply(...)` after the AvroIO sink and publish a message to PubSub.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you writing a message to a pub/sub topic when your pipeline(s) finishes. You don't need Dataflow to do this.

Comment: One may need to use the BlockingPipelineRunner( https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#blocking-execution) to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I have a similar use case, but my pipeline is running in streaming mode with an hourly interval. I want to publish a message to pubsub after each window's Write is compete.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to get notified when your pipeline finishes, and then subsequently publish a message - or do whatever you want to after the pipeline finishes running:

1. Use the `BlockingPipelineRunner`. This will run your pipeline [synchronously](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#blocking-execution).
2. Use the `DataflowPipelineRunner`. This will run your pipeline [asynchronously](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#asynchronous-execution). You can then poll the pipeline for its status, and wait for it to finish.

Comment: what about if the pipeline is executed in streaming mode with some window and we want to publish something to pubsub after window's write is complete?