# Streaming pipeline publish to pubsub after write step completes

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a use case where I have a Dataflow job running in streaming mode with an hourly fixed window.

When the pipeline runs for a given window, we calculate some data and write it to a data source. What I want to do next is publish some message to PubSub once the write is complete - how might I go about making sure that the write step is complete before writing to PubSub?

If the pipeline was executed in batch mode I know I could execute it in a blocking fashion as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526424/notifying-google-pubsub-when-dataflow-job-is-complete), but the tricky part is that this constantly running in streaming mode.

Comment: Where do you write? If in Storage, you could use [Pub/Sub notifications for Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)

Comment: Good point, thanks for clarifying - in this case I am writing to BigQuery, but the same issue would apply to any database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Wait.on()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) transform is designed for this use case. See documentation for usage example.

Comment: Thanks Raghu! That is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: According to the docs this should work, but for I/O write operation I am using BigqueryIO.Write, which results in a PDone, and Wait.on() is meant to be used with a PCollection - does that mean I have to write my own data sink, or is it possible to use with a provided method (I would really like to avoid reinventing the wheel).

Comment: check out http://osdir.com/apache-beam-users/msg02120.html for an example and a limitation: essentially need to do `Wait.on(writeResult.getFailedInserts())` - but this only works with streaming inputs at the moment

Comment: You are right. BigQueryIO is not updated yet to support this use case. Looks like it will be fixed soon [1]. Until then, it can't be used with Wait. 
[1]: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/4ed9a1be96f4bc47245299120f5d54ed0e28c072c0d4634e35e71031@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E